# "Unknown extension point" in plugin.xml problem

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In "Contributing to Eclipse" book it is written that to introduce an extension point you should type the next section in `plugin.xml`

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.contribution.junit.listeners">
    <listener
        class="org.eclipse.contribution.junit.RunTestAction$Listener">
    </listener>
</extension>
```

But this code gives me the "Unknown extension point" error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the book carefully, extension point is defined in the same plugin.xml as `<extension-point id="listeners" name="Test Listeners"/>`
Get sample code from Downloads at http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321205758

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin
    id="org.eclipse.contribution.junit"
    name="JUnit Plug-in"
    version="1.0.0"
    provider-name=""
    class="org.eclipse.contribution.junit.JUnitPlugin">

    <runtime>
        <library name="contribjunit.jar">
            <export name = "*"/>
        </library>      
    </runtime>

    <requires>
        <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources"/>
        <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui"/>
        <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.core"/>
        <import plugin="org.junit"/>
        <import plugin="org.eclipse.debug.core"/>
        <import plugin="org.eclipse.jdt.launching"/>
    </requires>

    <extension-point id="listeners" name="Test Listeners"/>

    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
        <objectContribution
            objectClass="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IType"
            id="org.eclipse.contribution.junit.runtest">
            <action
                label="Run Test"
                class="org.eclipse.contribution.junit.RunTestAction"
                enablesFor="1"
            id="org.eclipse.contribution.junit.runtest.action">
            </action>
        </objectContribution>
    </extension>

    <extension point="org.eclipse.contribution.junit.listeners">
        <listener
            class="org.eclipse.contribution.junit.RunTestAction$Listener">
        </listener>
    </extension>

</plugin>
```

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Aaargh, they just mentioned about it several paragraphs below. Its kinda unfair to introduce a confusion to resolve it in several paragraphs later. Thanks Max!